# examples from "Programming Entity Framework Code First book" don't create database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

[I was download examples from o'reilly site](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/downloads/) but they dont creates .sdf file. In book describes, by default, database is created  in bin/debug project folder. I have installed all needed components. Debuging is  passed successfully. Here source code:

```
namespace BreakAwayConsole
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Database.SetInitializer(
        new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BreakAwayContext>());

      InsertDestination();
    }

    private static void InsertDestination()
    {
      var destination = new Destination
      {
        Country = "Indonesia",
        Description = "EcoTourism at its best in exquisite Bali",
        Name = "Bali"
      };

      using (var context = new BreakAwayContext())
      {
        context.Destinations.Add(destination);
        context.SaveChanges();
      }
    }
  }
}

namespace DataAccess
{
  public class BreakAwayContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
  }
}
namespace Model
{
  public class Lodging
  {
    public int LodgingId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [MinLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public bool IsResort { get; set; }

    public Destination Destination { get; set; }
  }
  public class Destination
  {
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

    public List<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't specified connection string for your context, then by default database will be created at SQLEXPRESS server instead of sdf file in debug folder. Search for database named `DataAccess.BreakAwayContext` on your local SQLEXPRESS instance.

Comment: Where local SQLEXPRESS instance are located ? I searched it in root folder via windows explorer and don't find

Comment: @Ark it's a database server. Open *View > Server Explorer* and then enter server name `.\SQLEXPRESS` and select your database name in dropdown.

Comment: "could not be found" i also tried to connect to server "localhost\SQLEXPRESS" and again gets "could not be found" message. 
One connection is always exist its connection to My Name-PC server but in his dropdown list i can't see any database

Comment: @Ark make sure you don't have any connection string configured for your context in config file. Also you can easily find where database was created by looking at `context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` property

Comment: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=DataAccess.BreakAwayContext;Integrated Security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE
As i said one connection is always exist its connection to My Name-PC server. To add new connection i wrote down ".\SQLEXPRESS" into "Computer field" in  popup window "Add server"

Comment: @Ark as you can see, you have SQLEXPRESS installed, otherwise you'll get an error

Comment: Now have problem in that sqlexpress don't visualize which of property is primary or foreign key )

Comment: @Ark you can use Sql Server Management Studio to connect to SQLEXPRESS server and manage your data - I has much more features than Server Explorer built in Visual Studio